# AngularJS ui.router -- How to keep URL patterns manageable

Tags: angularjs

If we are using "ui.router" of angular JS module, will that module take control of all the URL navigation in the entire page?

I am using the $stateProvider.state method to register the mappings of URLs and States but as I am using it, I am observing that the state provider is taking control of routing all URL patters. For example, if I am having a jquery tabs pane in the same page somewhere, it is not working. The reason being, the jquery tabs are based on the HREF of the Anchors and this ui-router is taking charge of mapping them as well, to some states.

Can someone please confirm if it really is supposed to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, as per I know, it should work fine with HREF,for example

```
<a href="some-url">link</a>
```

In your case, for tabs you are specifying #(hash) in href and thats why its going through ui-router, I would suggest you to use `<uib-tab>` instead of simple jQuery tabs and thing will work as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using # in anchor tag then it will always try to match it with url and if not found then it will redirect to defualt one but you can actually intercept url change request in run function and use preventDefault function for specific request which will stop url change request